# How to resolve this "CWE-297: Improper Validation of Certificate with Host Mismatch " when using a code generator in gradle?

Tags: ssl-certificate, x509certificate

When scanning a microservice with veracode, it showed me an issue that I'm not aware of yet. Improper certificate validation with host mismatch, and debugging the code I couldn't understand how I could fix this failure, I would like some explanation about this problem and how I can fix it! enter image description here

on line 1418 where he complains, but it's inside the whole method that makes the things that need to happen!

I haven't tried to somehow fix it yet, as I haven't found any possible solutions!

```
private void applySslSettings() {
        try {
            TrustManager[] trustManagers;
            HostnameVerifier hostnameVerifier;
            if (!verifyingSsl) {
                trustManagers = new TrustManager[]{
                        new X509TrustManager() {
                            @Override
                            public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                            }

                            @Override
                            public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                                return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                            }
                        }
                };
                hostnameVerifier = new HostnameVerifier() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        return hostname.equals(session.getPeerHost());
                    }
                };
            } else {
                TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
                if (sslCaCert == null) {
                    trustManagerFactory.init((KeyStore) null);
                } else {
                    char[] password = null; // Any password will work.
                    CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                    Collection<? extends Certificate> certificates = certificateFactory.generateCertificates(sslCaCert);
                    if (certificates.isEmpty()) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException("expected non-empty set of trusted certificates");
                    }
                    KeyStore caKeyStore = newEmptyKeyStore(password);
                    int index = 0;
                    for (Certificate certificate : certificates) {
                        String certificateAlias = "ca" + Integer.toString(index++);
                        caKeyStore.setCertificateEntry(certificateAlias, certificate);
                    }
                    trustManagerFactory.init(caKeyStore);
                }
                trustManagers = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
                hostnameVerifier = OkHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE;
            }

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3");
            sslContext.init(keyManagers, trustManagers, new SecureRandom());
            httpClient = httpClient.newBuilder()
                            .sslSocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory(), (X509TrustManager) trustManagers[0])
                            .hostnameVerifier(hostnameVerifier)
                            .build();
        } catch (GeneralSecurityException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
```